# Pass URL Parameters to HTML Form Google Web App

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, url-parameters

I've gone through most of the relating questions regarding this and haven't found a solution that helps me (I've applied them one by one).  I have an HTML form that I am publishing as a web app through google.  I need to prefill an input box with that parameter.

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('html')
        .evaluate();      
          }
```

html.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<form>
  <h1><center>Verification</center></h1>
  Form ID:<input type="number" name="formid" id="formid" class="formid">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said, I've tried many suggestions in similiar questions, but can't seem to find one that works.  The id is that I can type in my url + ?formid= and have that populate in the input.  How can I make this happen as described?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When Web Apps is accessed with the URL of `url + ?formid=###`, you want to put the value of `###` to the text box.

  - The URL is like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?formid=###`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, I used `google.script.url.getLocation()` for retrieving the query parameter.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `html.html` as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<form>
  <h1><center>Verification</center></h1>
  Form ID:<input type="number" name="formid" id="formid" class="formid">
</form>
<script>
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    document.getElementById("formid").value = location.parameters.formid[0];
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- By above modification, when you accessed to Web Apps with `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?formid=12345`, `12345` is put to the text box.

#### Reference:

- [getLocation(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url#getlocationfunction)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: That is perfect and elegantly simple!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @NMALM Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(v){
    $('#formid').val(v);
   })
   .getTheValueOfV();
});
</scrip>
```

With Regular JavaScript

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(v){
     document.getElementById('formId').value=v;
   })
  .getTheValueOfV();
};
</script>
```

Code.gs:

```
function getTheValueOfV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  return ss.getRangeByName("TheRangeWhereYouFindtheValueofv").getValue();
}
```

You can put the script in the head or in the body your choice.  If you use JQuery you need something like this in the head.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```