# Google Email: Button/Link which trigger a script for sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to send an email with Google App Script (I know how to do that) which includes an approval button/link. When the user clicks the link/button in the email to approve the request, I want to trigger a script (this is the part I do not know if possible from email) which goes back to the Google Sheet and changes a value in a cell.

Example:
User A submits a request using google form, and a new row is appended in SheetA. With some formulas, I automatically associate an ID = X to that request/row. A script will then send an email to user B to ask to approve the request of user A. User B will click a link in the email and the script will find the record X in SheetA and update a value in that row.

Comment: I think this is a good question, would you mind cleaning it up a little? I think it could be much shorter and concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a simple web app, using code like

```
function doGet(e) {
  params = e.parameter;

  var range=e.parameter.range;
  var value=e.parameter.value;

  SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID').getRange(range).setValue(value);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<b>${range}</b> set to <b>${value}</b>`);
}
```

publish it with "execute as me", "everyone, even anonymous" options,
and then exec it using a link

https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPTID/exec?range=B1&value=100

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jNEzil1dOtXj-Qc5ZVcZnd1fwGQ7V18irWIsH9G8to8/edit?usp=sharing

Update link:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5KYzQELQNS0y0uf0CwjwzoWkabCJywqkpph7wUUXoTGjERUg/exec?range=Sheet1!B1&value=500

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a prefect way to do this, but with a small work-around, it is possible.

Instead of "clicking an Approve button," the user could click an Approve link. This link would open a Google Form that is [pre-filled](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en) with the a request ID and Marked as Approved. All they would need to do is submit the pre-filled form. The email would also contain a Reject link that would also pre-fill the request_id and mark Reject. (I recommend radio buttons for this question)

Then set up a trigger [onFormSumit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()). for this form that makes the appropriate edits to the spreadsheet when a user submits this form.

If you wanted to make the solution even more complicated, but perhaps avoid the second click, the links could be to a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and you could code the site to automatically record the data [in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757625/pass-url-parameters-to-html-form-google-web-app) to Google sheet.

PS: Both solutions also work as a way to get read receipts for emails sent from Google Scripts.

Comment: I am going to hold for another day, but I thought about something similar to your second solution and I will probably go for that. Thanks!