# Unable to access content of API made in apps-script

Tags: api, authentication, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I tried to make an API using apps-script doGet() function.
I am able access the content of this API on my browser using appropriate authentication steps but am unable to access the same using another apps-script project.

The API looks as follows and is published as web app.

```js
function doGet(request){
  var parameters = request.parameters;
  var request_id = parameters.id;
  var response_obj = getObjectById(request_id);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response_obj)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

and request is simply made using

```js
const content = UrlFetchApp(url).getContentText();
```

is there a fundamental mistake or is there an authentication procedure that can be carried out so as to access this content

**Answer found thanks for the help guys**

what i needed was an authentication procedure and apps-script is very generous with that

refer [Using AuthToken obtained via ScriptApp.getAuthToken() to call web apps in GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534493/using-authtoken-obtained-via-scriptapp-getauthtoken-to-call-web-apps-in-gas)

I was able to implement the solution using the following snippet for authentication

```js
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var header = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token};
  var options = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers": header,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
const content =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```

Comment: If you publish the app with "Anyone, even anonymous" no auth is required. Does it work from browser? From incognito window?

Comment: yes i tried using  'Anyone, even anonymous option' in incognito ... it still asked for a google id but i was able to view the content in incognito after entering it ..... the urlfetch app returns html to the authentication page

Comment: "Run as me", not "User running the app"?

Comment: This is my example of simple web app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924391/google-email-button-link-which-trigger-a-script-for-sheet/61926345#61926345 It isn't exactly your case but it takes parameter and runs function anonymously

Comment: it is still the same ... even with 'Anyone, even anonymous' and 'execute as me' trying the url in incognito it asks for a google id(any) but displays the content

Answer (score 0):

The line

`const content = UrlFetchApp(url).getTextContent();`

should be

`const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();`

See the documentation for `UrlFetchApp` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext).

Comment: sorry my fault in framing the question actual code uses getContentText